# Design with multiple Expanders

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need a little help in creating the design I want.
My ViewModel has three collections which are bound to three `ItemsControl`s using Caliburn.Micro. Each collection contains between 10 and 31 items.
I want to put each `ItemControl` into an `Expander`. So far, so simple:

```
<StackPanel>
  <Expander IsExpanded="True" Header="Day recordings">
    <ItemsControl Name="DayRecordings" />
  </Expander>
  <Expander IsExpanded="False" Header="Month recordings">
    <ItemsControl Name="MonthRecordings" />
  </Expander>
  <Expander IsExpanded="False" Header="Digit recordings">
    <ItemsControl Name="DigitRecordings" />
  </Expander>
</StackPanel>
```

The problem now is that they expand beyond the bounds of the `StackPanel` they are contained in.
I would like the `Expander`s to behave like this:

1. If only one `Expander` is expanded, it should use the complete space of the `StackPanel` minus the space needed for the other, not-expanded `Expander`s. Inside the expanded `Expander` a vertical `ScrollBar` should be shown.
2. If N `Expander`s are expanded, each should take 1/Nth of the total space of the `StackPanel` minus the space needed for the other, not-expanded `Expander`s. In each of the expanded `Expander`s a vertical `ScrollBar` should be shown.

   1. If one of the expanded `Expander`s needs less space than the assigned 1/Nth, it should only use the needed space and the excess space should be evenly distributed to the other expanded `Expander`s. This behavior is nice-to-have but not essential

Unfortunately, I don't have more than the simple XAML from above, because I don't even have an idea on how to tackle this...

Comment: We've had this question before, probably impossible to find...

Comment: @H.B.: I might be using the wrong keywords, but I am unable to find a similar question. Please be so kind and mark it as a duplicate, so I can find it.

Comment: +1 cause I don't know why this should have a down vote

Comment: I have not tested this so it is a comment but you might be able to use a Grid and converter for Height where you pass IsExpanded and return Auto or *.  That less then 1/Nth space is too much for a converter.

Comment: @Blam: Thanks for your comment. Any idea how you would go about solving 2.1. if you think it is too much for a converter?

Answer (score 1):

Use a ScrollViewer, put a Grid in it, set row heights to auto. 
Put a converter on MaxHeight if you want some fancy layout.

Comment: The `Grid` inside the `ScrollViewer` will show one `Scrollbar` outside the `Expander`s and not one `ScrollBar` inside each `Expander`.

Comment: Then a ScrollViewer for each ItemsControl.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [accordion](http://wpf.codeplex.com/) control from the toolkit to get the required behavior.

Comment: The last release is two years old and the reviews state that there are a lot of bugs. That's not what I want to use.